# Refracting telescope image formation

Tags: geometric-optics, telescopes

I'm having some trouble understanding how a refracting telescope forms a magnified image for an object that is not assumed to be infinitely far away. I drew this ray diagram: [image]

And as you can see, a real and diminished image is formed. I would like to know whether or not this diagram is correct, and if not, what would be the appropriate diagram?

Comment: The relative placements of your lenses is wrong. The idea is, that the second lens creates a virtual image of an intermediate real image formed by the first lens. The magnification is then defined by the change in viewing angle when compared to the naked eye (of course a telescope cannot create a magnified real image of a planet or star, that would be pretty useless). See also: [Wikipedia on magnification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnification).

Comment: the diagram per se is correct

Comment: Technically, a "telescope" does not produce a real image, just a magnified field-of view (smaller FOV, greater resolution). It's followed with a "camera lens" which produces the real image.